# Access Too Few Parameters Error

Tags: ms-access

I have this code I have been working on to add data to a table. And there is a portion of code that is being highlighted with the error message RUN TIME ERROR 3061: TOO FEW PARAMETERS. EXPECTED 1

And I cannot figure out what the issue is and what I am missing. The following is the portion of code being highlighted.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO KWTable(KW, Source, Code) " & _
" VALUES(" & Me.text_key & ",'" & Me.txt_code & "','" & _
Me.combo_source & "')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 dim ssql as string
    ssql = "INSERT INTO KWTable(KW, Source, Code) " & _
    " VALUES(" & Me.text_key & ",'" & Me.txt_code & "','" & _
    Me.combo_source & "')"
    debug.print ssql
    CurrentDb.Execute ssql
```

Comment: I tried that and now I am getting the same error, but it is highlighting the CURRENTDB.EXECUTE SSQL